# Is it possible to access class prototype's property?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, abstract-class

I got a question but i don't know have the right words to ask it in just one phrase.
I'm writing my code in TypeScript and I want to achieve the following:

I got an abstract "Resource" class

```js
// Resource.ts
abstract class Resource {
  public abstract readonly type: string;
  protected _id?: string;

  get id() {
    return this._id;
  }

  public static info() {
    return {
      type: this.prototype.type
    };
  }
}
```

and, let's say, a Post resource class that inherits from the abstract class

```js
class PostResource extends Resource {
  public readonly type = 'post'
}
```

I want to access the "type" property from the PostResource class prototype like I tried to do with the `Resource.info()` static method. Obviously, it returns `undefined`.

I also tried to instanciate the class inside the static method like that

```js
public static info() {
  return {
    type: (new this()).type
  }
}
```

but it throws an Error because I can't instanciate Resource as it is an abstract class.

I atempted to use static properties as well :

```js
abstract class Resource {
  public static readonly type: string;

  public static info() {
    return {
      type: this.type
    }
  }
}

class PostResource extends Resource {
  public static readonly type = 'post';
}
```

That theoricaly works, but then I loose all the benefits of inheritance because static propeties and methods cannot be abstract. For example, I could create a PostResource with no `type` static property and TypeScript would not warn me. `type` would then be `undefined`, which is not good because all Resource-extended class should have a `type` property.

So I'm looking for a solution to allow me to access all properties initialized in a Resource-extended class.

I hope my question is clear, thank you for your help !

EDIT:

I should give more details about my final goal.
I would like to have a list of classes that inherit Resource abstract class, and therefore have a "type" property. Ideally it should be a static property, cause I could simply iterate over the classes and just access the property.
But I also need this value inside the instances of this class, so for example i could have something like that:

```js
console.log(PostResource.type); // > 'post'
const post1 = new PostResource();
console.log(post1.type); // > 'post';
```

Answer (score 0):

What about having a property `_type` in the abstract class and initializing it in constructor of subclasses?

```
abstract class Resource {

  protected _type: string;

  constructor(type: string) {
    this._type = type;
  }

  public info() {
    return {
      type: this._type
    }
  }
}

class PostResource extends Resource {
  constructor() {
    super('post');
  }
}

class GetResource extends Resource {
  constructor() {
    super('get');
  }
}

let postResource = new PostResource();
let getResource = new GetResource();

console.log(postResource.info()); // {type: 'post'}
console.log(getResource.info()); // {type: 'get'}
```

#### Edit

I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, but here's an example for your updated requirements:

```
abstract class Resource {

}

class PostResource extends Resource {
  static type = 'post';
  public type = 'post';
}

let postResource = new PostResource();

console.log(PostResource.type); // post
const post1 = new PostResource();
console.log(post1.type); // post
```

Comment: Yeah it's also a possibility but my goal is to avoid the instanciation of the class to get the "type" property.
The idea is to get the value of the parameters that are initialized in the constructor without instanciate it. I know it sounds weird but I wonder if this is possible.
Actually the real problem is that we can't have properties that are abstract and static so i'm looking for a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Actually your attempt with instantiating the class inside the static method can work, you just need a proper typing for `this`:

```
public static info(this: new () => Resource) {
  return {
    type: new this().type
  }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgSgUzAewFcpZsEBvAKAQQAcCRkBLWBUSGeBKbYAEzwB2yAJ4IIwmtgBcCdowEBzANwUqtekxaRgEZgnkAzPAAoIAC0ZgZA7AHcExgJQIAvAD4suQsWzPK1am4IIgFyNQCxCWkEG3tzSycAOnFJcIQAXzVMzIoUNAwABTxIHHwiEgRsAA8IbAFeDFLvCv91Bj1uPkERSMlXBAByGmKIAZUc2EF8ZGxE5DwFYyKSr3LZwxNHRyA)

[More info](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#this-parameters) on function's `this` parameter annotation.